# Why does value from MouseEvent change randomly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseevent, event-listener, mousemove

Hey I want to move svg Elements. I call this function with a mousemove EventListener. I just take the current Mouseposition minus the start point of the svg element. Then I prepare a string with the values to use it in tarnsform Attribute. The thing is when I dont't set the Attribute I always have the correct values for translate. But when I set the Attribute it always switches between a value near the origin and the right value.

```
elementDrag(event) {
        if (this.selectedElement && event.target.type != "textarea") {
        let coord = this.getMousePosition(event);
        //console.log(this.offset.x, this.offset.y);
        let x = coord.x - this.start.x;
        let y = coord.y - this.start.y;
        console.log(x,y);
        this.translate = "translate(";
        this.translate += x + ",";
        this.translate += y + ")";
        this.translate = this.translate.toString();


        //when i comment this line out I have always the right translate 
        this.selectedElement.setAttribute("transform", this.translate);

        }
    }
```

Iam thankful for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `transform` is not a valid HTMLElement attribute. It is a CSS property of the `style` attribute.

So instead of `setAttribute()` you need to set the `style.transform` equal to `this.translate`.

[HTML Attribute Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)